# TemplateSyntaxError: Caught ImportError while rendering: No module named html5lib

Tags: python, django, linux, pip

Ok so I have a site with a fairly old version of Django and i'm currently to setup a dev site based on the live site.

So i've created the `virtualenv` and gone through and installed the dependencies to the site. I've backed up the live database and restored on the live site. However when i access the URL of the website I get a `error 505`. So i've looked in the the log files and getting the above error.

But if i run:

```
>>> import html5lib
>>> html5lib.__file__
```

It outputs where it's installed correctly.

```
'/var/www/website/path/lib/python2.6/site-packages/html5lib/__init__.pyc'
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Looks like your website is configured to use system python instead of the one from virtualenv.

Comment: you forgot to do `source bin/activate` from your venv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out where i had copied the files across from the live site, my wsgi file was still pointing at the live vertualenv.

```
import os
import sys
import site
site.addsitedir('/var/www/path/to/file/lib/python2.6/site-packages')
```